PYPDF2 List index out of range while merging pdfs
the code was working fine on a small sample of file when i tried to use it on 2000 files it didn't work the files are ordered from 1 to 2000+
The CODE
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger #pip install PyPDF2


def merge_pdf(first_list,second_list ,first_folder , second_folder ,output_folder):
        if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
                os.mkdir(output_folder)

        first_list = [f for f in os.listdir(first_folder) if f.endswith('.pdf')]
        second_list = [f for f in os.listdir(second_folder) if f.endswith('.pdf')]

        for pdf in first_list :
                key = pdf.split('.')[0]
                matching_draft = [f for f in second_list if key in f][0]
                merger = PdfMerger()
                merger.append(f"{first_folder}/{pdf}")
                merger.append(f"{second_folder}/{matching_draft}")
                merger.write(f"{output_folder}/{matching_draft}") 
                print (f'Merged {len(first_list)}, PDFS to {output_folder}')

merge_pdf('first_list','second_list','first_folder','second_folder','output_folder') 



The Error
  File "F:\New folder\Tarek\New folder\Merger2.py", line 21, in <module>
    merge_pdf('first_list','second_list','first_folder','second_folder','output_folder')
  File "F:\New folder\Tarek\New folder\Merger2.py", line 14, in merge_pdf
    matching_draft = [f for f in second_list if key in f][0]
IndexError: list index out of range 



PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.
